# How compare two excel file in python?

Tags: python, excel, join, compare

I want to compare two excel in python.
Excel number 1 is the same as the sample and has all the columns ""
example :
"189941","male"

Excel number 2 is the same as the sample and has not all the columns ""
example :
50756   4f5e3a72e4b053fd6a4313f6

I want to compare two excel and if the first column is the same, the first and second columns of excel number 1 and the second column of excel number 2 into a new excel.

```html
with open('data/datasets/users.csv', 'r') as t1, open('data/datasets/checkins.csv', 'r') as t2, open(
        'data/datasets/user_gender.csv', 'w') as t3:
    requrementUsersDic = {}
    temp = False
    for line in t1:
        if temp == False:
            temp = True
            continue
        userId = line.split(',')[0]
        gender = line.split(',')[1]
        requrementUsersDic[userId] = gender
checkins = []

for item in requrementUsersDic:
    with open('data/datasets/checkins.csv', 'r') as chk:
        for line in chk:
            if line.__contains__(item[1:len(item) - 1]):
                t3.write(requrementUsersDic[item].replace("\"", "") + '___' + line)
                # chk.close()
```

And the result is:
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.

Comment: You are using `t3` inside the second `with` where it was already closed.

Comment: You are not dealing with Excel `.xlsx`, read [CSV File Reading and Writing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#module-csv)